# Routing requests from IIS to Jetty with isapi_redirect (tomcat connector)

Tags: iis, hudson, jetty, windows-server-2003, isapi-redirect

I have installed the isapi_redirect into IIS, and allowed to run.
I have enabled the ajp13 in Jetty and I can telnet to port 8009.
This is my current uiworkermap.properties:

```
/hudson=jetty
/hudson/*=jetty
```

If I make a request to "http://localhost/hudson" or any subdirectory I get a 404 error.
All the other urls return the site defined in IIS.
This tells me that the isapi_redirect is looking at the uiworkermap file and trying to redirect correctly.

In the Jetty log and in the isapi_redirect log I don't see any errors.
If I go to http://localhost:8008/hudson I see it correctly.
Do you have any idea what could cause this?

**UPDATE:** I created a virtual directory with name "Jakarta" that pointed to the isapi_redirect dll like it is said here: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html
After this step the error changed, now in the browser I see:

```
Bad Gateway!

There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

Jakarta/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.32 ()
```

In the error log (in debug mode) I can see that it first connects and the request is made but there is no response from jetty, and this error is generated:

[error] ajp_get_reply::jk_ajp_common.c (2118): (jetty) Tomcat is down or refused connection. No response has been sent to the client (yet)

This is the part of the log with the request and error: 
https://rapidshare.com/files/3999719393/isapi_redirect_log.txt

Comment: This is just a problem with an installation it shouldn't be too hard. Any suggestion would be appreciated. You don't have to have the full answer, I will follow the steps and troubleshouting you might suggest and I will award the bounty to the user who helped me the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, in the end not having any help from stackoverflow users and also reading that in the official Jetty site about ajp13:

> It is recommended to NOT use the AJP protocol, and superior
>   performance and clearer semantics will be achieve using HTTP.

I gave up on ajp and used a great and well documented open source dll to have HTTP proxy functions in IIS, [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/).

So I would suggest anyone who has similar issues to just use an HTTP proxy instead.